# PyStan fails with Segfault when running basic probit model

Tags: python, statistics, pystan

I am getting familiar with PyStan. I have run several models including a Bayesian linear regression model without issue. However, when I try to run the following code I get a seg fault error:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Interestingly, this only occurs *after* the burn-in iterations have completed. My model code is here. I am currently making up some data and trying to infer the parameters `beta_tru_1` and `alpha`. The model code comes from the [Stan User's Guide](https://mc-stan.org/docs/2_26/stan-users-guide/logistic-probit-regression-section.html).

```
import pystan
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm

# the params
beta_tru_1 = 3.7
alpha = 2.3

# make some data
n = 1000
np.random.seed(1)
x1 = norm(0, 1).rvs(n)
z = alpha + x1 * beta_tru_1
y = [1 if i > 0.7 else 0 for i in norm.cdf(z)]

# train test split
y_train, y_test = y[:750], y[750:]
x_train, x_test = x1[:750], x1[750:]

# stan code
probit_code = """
data {
    int<lower=0> n; // number of data vectors
    real x[n]; // data matrix
    int<lower=0,upper=1> y[n]; // response vector
}
parameters {
    real beta; // regression coefs
    real alpha;
}
model {
    for (i in 1:n)
      y[i] ~ bernoulli(Phi(alpha + beta * x[i]));
}
"""

# compile the model
probit_model = pystan.StanModel(model_code=probit_code)

# the data
probit_dat = {
    "n": len(y_train),
    "y": y_train,
    "x": x_train
}

# fit the model (small number of iterations for debug)
# this is where the error is
probit_fit = probit_model.sampling(data=probit_dat, iter=500, warmup=500, chains=4, init="0")
```

I am using PyStan v. 2.19.1.1 and python 3.7.6 on Linux Pop OS 20.10. I have run this code on multiple machines including an Ubuntu container with no luck. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try running your program with `strace` to get more information about the crash; ideally you would be able to see what the program was trying to do when it crashed. It might also be possible to execute Python from `gdb` and get more information that way (just guessing here, I haven't tried it). A Stan-specific forum might be able to give you more focused advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to determine the cause of this error. The arguments I was using for the  `probit_model.sampling` parameters were causing a problem. Specifically, the `iter` and `warmups` parameter cannot be the same. The `iter` parameter is the *total* number of iterations including the "burn-in" iterations specified through the `warmup` parameter. Thus the inputs I was specifying caused `probit_model.sampling` to perform the 500 burn-in iterations and then sampling was ceased rather than performing another 500 iterations for 1000 total HMC iterations.

The correct parameter setting for this behavior would be:

```
probit_model.sampling(data=probit_dat, iter=1000, warmup=500)
```

I have tested this solution, and it performs as intended. (Though this number of samples is not sufficient for valid inference in this problem.)